# TFS2015 Powershell on Target Machine

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to pass some data to a remote powershell script within the TFS2015 build step.

My step is calling a remote Powershell script on a target machine.  I am passing data as script parameters.  The following script parameters are what I have defined.

This parameter list works:
-buildVersion $(Build.BuildNumber) -queuedBy $env:USERNAME  (but the name is the account running the script)

,but I really want the Build.QueuedBy  username to get passed so I have tried:

-queuedBy $(Build.QueuedBy)

….or

-queuedBy $env:BUILD_QUEUEDBY

This does not work.  Am I specifying something incorrectly or is there a better way?

I would also like to get some of the Build definition Variables to the remote script as well.

I have displayed the variables available to me with a Command line step running:    cmd   /k set

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the correct value you need something like this:

```
$a = Get-Item -Path "Env:BUILD_QUEUEDBY"
$a = $a.Value
```